# How does R package 'quantmod' receive (almost) real-time data?

Tags: r

I'm interested in `quantmod` R package's data extraction methods/algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing `quantmod` package's documentation ([the up-to-date one](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf), located on CRAN, since documentation on the package's website is obsolete), it appears that, currently, `R` package `quantmod` supports, aside from *local* data sets (MySQL, CSV, RData), the following public and private **online data sources** (availability varies from function to function).

- [**Yahoo Finance**](http://finance.yahoo.com)
- [**Google Finance**](http://www.google.com/finance)
- [**Federal Reserve Economic Data (FRED)**](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2)
- [**Oanda**](http://www.oanda.com)